# You're providing a directory outside the import directory defined into `dbms.directories.import`

Tags: json, neo4j

I'm trying to import an json file to neo4j, but it shows this error. I already changed the settings and imported the file to the right location.
Can please someone help?
Thank you in advance.

Cypher statement: //Load_JSON_Country

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///countries.json")
YIELD value
```

Settings: #apoc

```
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=true
```

> Error: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.json`: Caused by:
> java.io.IOException: You're providing a directory outside the import
> directory defined into `dbms.directories.import`

Comment: where is the countries.json file located ? in the 'import' folder of neo4j or elsewhere ?

Comment: yes, in the import folder of neo4j

Comment: check the config for this line:
dbms.directories.import=import

Comment: @DavidAStumpf the line is correct. I tried to comment but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is on the following link!
https://community.neo4j.com/t/youre-providing-a-directory-outside-the-import-directory-defined-into-dbms-directories-import/48562?u=mariana

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).